# java jspinner change listener trigger

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have 2 comboboxes and a spinner, that work like this: if the selected item of the first combo is changed, the second combo keeps its selected item but re-calls the spinner (the spinner is linked only to the second box). My problem is that I can't trigger the stateChange listener of the spinner when I do this.

Here is the code for forcing the second box to reselect its last item when the first one is changed (nothing wrong here, it works just fine):

```
String orientare = (String) orientareComboBox.getSelectedItem();
orientareComboBox.setSelectedItem(orientare);
```

This is the code for the second box actionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String value = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("oblica"))
            {
                unghiSpinner.setEnabled(true);

                double unghi = (double) unghiSpinner.getValue();
                unghiSpinner.setValue(new Double(unghi));

            }
}
```

And the spinner's Listener:

```
           public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
        {
            if (unghiSpinner.isEnabled())
            {
               // do something
            }
        }
```

I do not know what command I should use for `unghiSpinner` to trigger its listener, because `setValue()` can't do it.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are _not_ showing ;-) setValue should work just fine. Best to show an SSCCE so we can see what goes wrong.

Comment: i would, but the amount of code is huge and not so well written. so, setValue() should trigger the changeListener ... i'll have another look on my code and if i can't find the mistake i will try to show as much relevant code as i can. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you changing the value of your JSpinner in the code above. It appears that all you do is set the spinner's value to the same value that it held previously, and that shouldn't trigger the listener. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: no, i don't, as i want to pass the same value to the method called by the spinner. i should change the value to `0` for e.g. and set the value after, to trigger it?

Comment: Try it and see. But wouldn't it make sense that a change listener is triggered by *change*?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i set the value to `0` and back to the old value, and it worked. I didn't know that the changeListener does not trigger if the value is the same, i thought it takes actions when it's text area is tempered with. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post my suggestion as an answer since it worked.

Comment: Given a large code base, you should construct an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to narrow the scope of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see you changing the value of your JSpinner in the code above. It appears that all you do is set the spinner's value to the same value that it held previously, and that shouldn't trigger the listener. To trigger a change listener to fire you must change the state of the observed entity.